# Custom NTLM authentication with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ntlmv2

I need to authenticate to a server which exposes a custom NTLM-based authentication scheme, using the standard HttpWebRequest object.
It's pretty much basic NTLM except that during the NTLM handshake protocol I receive a cookie from the server which I must send back during the handshake, otherwise the authentication will fail.

My question is: how do I hook into the HttpWebRequest's handshake protocol so that I can add the cookies in the header, during the handshake?

Comment: At what point in the three way handshake is the cookie sent by the server?

Comment: It is sent when I receive the Type 2 message from the server

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the Get Response method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

Comment: No, because I need to intercept the second step in the NTLM authentication to add my custom header, but the entire authentication is made transparent by .NET; GetResponse() will only serve the *final* response.